# Computing a single regression line with confidence intervals for multiple regression lines

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, spss, sas, excel

I have multiple regression lines for individual groups (predicted values stored in a data set). I want to compute a single overall quadratic regression fit with confidence intervals for these individual regression lines.
I would then like to obtain the values of confidence intervals at specific points for the purpose of creating a table.

I have uploaded a picture at [http://imgur.com/9wWdcjr](https://imgur.com/9wWdcjr) showing individual regression lines. I have manually added an 'overall avg. regression line' for the rest with confidence interval lines just to give an idea of what I want to do.

 
Any solution will be greatly appreciated, but if someone could show me a way to do it in SPSS / SAS or Excel, it will be greatly appreciated, especially from predicted values.
Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.  Could you provide a small example, and illustration, or describe your models rigorously in mathematical notation?  And could you expand on exactly how an "overall quadratic regression fit with confidence intervals" would be related to the original "regression lines"?

Comment: I'm not sure if individual regression lines can be combined. Have you tried to fit quadratic regression on the entire data?

Comment: @JaehyeonKim, Yes I did. But the issue is that some groups have more data points (e.g. 12) vs others (e.g. 4). So when I fit quadratic regression to entire data, the model gets biased in the favor of groups with more data points. Thank you.